# Merging multiple CodeIgniter's controllers into same view

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have a controller that displays the site layout, then I have another controller that manages emails. My question is how can I combine them onto the same page(same view) do I just add the functions of my email controller to my site controller? So that site controller has the send() method, then move everything from my "newsletter" view into my "home" view?

### Site Controller

```
<?php

      class Site extends CI_Controller 
   {

    function index()
      {
        $this->load->model('site_model');
        $data['records']= $this->site_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
      }

   }

 ?>
```

### Email Controller

```
class Email extends CI_Controller{


    function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('newsletter');
    }

    function send()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        //field name, error message, validaion rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Email Address', 'required');


        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('newsletter');

        }

        else
        {
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');

        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


        $this->email->from('', '');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('This is an email test');
        $this->email->message('Sucess');

        $path = $this->config->item('server_root');
        $file = $path  .'CodeTest/attachments/newsletter1.txt';

        $this->email->attach($file);

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo ' Your email has been sent.';
        }

        else {

            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());

             }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: So you want a single controller? or you want to share the view?

Comment: I'm not sure which is better? I do want them to share the same view though.

Comment: Your approach is fine.. If you want to share the view then add a new method in your Site controller and load the same view. If you want to share the functionallity then copy the code (but that's redundant). You could also redirect to the other controller.

Comment: I think you are going to want to read more about the [MVC approach](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html). It sounds like your email controller should be a model and it should be loaded into your controller. Then your controller will have the email validation. The form will submit to your controller. Chat with me if you want to work through this.

Comment: Or you may want to research using templates.

Comment: @J.Money I don't want to turn it into a model that sounds like too much effort, it's working fine now i'm just wondering how to integrate them into the same page.

Comment: There is 1 controller method per URL. You can't use 2 controllers for 1 page request. That is why you should re-read the MVC approach.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are trying to use the site controller as a template, in which case, you should learn about using templates.

Answer (score 0):

did you remove this code blocks from your method which in site controller?
this code forward you automatically to newsletter page. You have to remove it from your site controller

```
if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
  $this->load->view('newsletter');
}
```